# Align field correctly in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Good day, please am new to blackberry development and i am trying to achieve the following look on the screen:

text1 -------------------- text2

image--------------------text3

Assuming that text1 and text2 is the left and right end of the screen and image and text3 are below them respectively(forget the lines). How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

use the field manager either vertical or horizontal field manager as per your requirement.
remember adding the field manager, whichever u use......

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To give a full answer maybe we will need more info but I'll give you something that would let you start.

You have to work with managers.

I would add a VerticalFieldManager and to that VFM I would add two HorizontalFieldManager.
The first HFM containing two LabelFields and the second one the image and another Labelfield.

In the style of the labelField and image you will have to include FIELD_RIGTH or FIELD_LEFT so each element is placed in the correct location.

This is from de official docs, it may help you. (consider reading the rest of the page)
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Manager_1579416_11.jsp

Comment: thank you very much. By the way, the texts will change dynamically, so is it not better to use a textfield or will label field do the trick?  thanks once again.

Comment: Hi Manuel, I dont think either the textField or the labelFiled cause a problem, though they are dynamic.